# apache authenication - how to supress or bypass for users from within network

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication

I have below conf to allow users from within our company's network to access access the site without userid or password.

```
    <Location />
      Require valid-user
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from 1XX.2XX.0.0/16
      Allow from 10.0.0.0/8
      Allow from 127.0.0.1  
      Satisfy Any

      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Enter your ID and password"
      AuthBasicProvider ldap
      Include /abc/httpd/conf/ldap_userinfo.conf   

      AuthLDAPGroupAttribute member

      ### Add application ldap-user/ldap-group below ###        
      Require ldap-group CN=AP-ABC-PREVIEWSITE-USERS,OU=GROUPS,OU=ABC INFRASTRUCTURE,DC=i,DC=abc,DC=com
      ErrorDocument 401 "Please use correct id and password for access to         this site"

    </Location>
```

After adding, users are seeing the prompt to enter user id and password but can hit cancel and access the site. How can i suppress the prompt as well?

Comment: Eventually found out, we enabled basic auth on the backend tomcat as well. After it was removed, this configuration worked without any issues.

Comment: Can you set your comment as anwser and mark it as valid ? Thanks